# How to focus and select a checkbox using React ref?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, use-ref

I have been looking around a method to correctly **focus** and **select** a checkbox in React code.
The methods `focus()` and `select()` that I'm using in the example below are not working :

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export const HelloWorld = () => {
  const checkboxref = useRef(null);

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    checkboxref.current.focus();
    checkboxref.current.select();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Focus</button>
      <input type="checkbox" ref={checkboxref} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I click on the button, my checkbox is not focused and not selected...

Any solution please ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You click a button and I bet the button has focus after you released your mousebutton. Try starting a timer and see if it works

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a separate function to handle onChange event

```js
const checkboxref = useRef(null);
```

You can simply get the current value of the checkbox with:

```js
checkboxref.current.checked 
// which returns a boolean
```

Answer (score 2):

use this one it might help you. here I am using createRef instead of useRef and also uses the callback hook which ensures the availability of ref when you click the button.

```
import React,{createRef, useCallback} from 'react';


export const HelloWorld = () => {
  const checkboxref = createRef();

  const handleOnClick = useCallback(() => {
    const node = checkboxref.current;
    if(node){
     node.focus();
     node.select();
     }
  }, [checkboxref]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Focus</button>
      <input type="checkbox" ref={checkboxref} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I didn't know that we could also use ```createRef()``` in a functional component. But I don't know what is the difference between these two functions ?

Answer (score 1):

The `select` methods selects text in elements such as text inputs and text areas, so I'm not sure what effect you expect it to have on the checkbox. As for `focus`, it can focus, but again, there is not much you can do with a focused checkbox. I can only think of styling it https://jsfiddle.net/4howanL2/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. I didn't set the focus style for my checkbox input, it's why I didn't see any effect :)

Comment: On the ```select``` method, I was thinking it could be the method that permit to tick the checkbox

Comment: Happy to help! If you want to check your checkbox you need to do this instead `checkboxref.current.checked=true;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select and focus it:

```
checkboxref.current.checked = true;
```

when you make it checked = true, it will focus it as well